# Call webservice asynchronously

Tags: android, web-services, asynchronous, xamarin, async-await

I need to call a web service so I added the webservice as web reference and I am able to call it. Now I need to make that call async because it need to download lot of data and it is taking lot of time. I tried to use the async/await method but I can not do this since the method in the webservice are not async.

Original code:

```
 public static void validateLogin(JsonParameters _param, ref ValidateCredentials result, ref string excep_error)
    {
        var _mobileService = new MobileService();
        _mobileService.Url = AppParam.IISSTRING + "/UrlAddressReference";
        try
        {
            result = _mobileService.downloaddata(_param);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            excep_error = ex.Message;
        }

    }
```

I tried to add async task in place of void to make the method async, but how can I await the webservice response?

After I added the webservice as a web reference I can see that it created for each method in it an async method and completed event. How can I make use of them? (Ex: `downloaddata", a method name`downloaddataasync`, and an event "downloaddatacompleted")

Is there a way to do this or do I need to change the webservice?

Comment: What does the implementation of the `MobileService.downloaddata` call look like, because that is where this would more than likely need to start from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public async static Task validateLogin(JsonParameters _param, ref ValidateCredentials result, ref string excep_error)
        {
          await Task.Run(()=>
          {
            var _mobileService = new MobileService();
            _mobileService.Url = AppParam.IISSTRING + "/UrlAddressReference";
            try
            {
                result = _mobileService.downloaddata(_param);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                excep_error = ex.Message;
            }
         });
}
```

Comment: I would like to know too

Answer (score 1):

> After I added the webservice as a web reference I can see that it created for each method in it an async method and completed event. How can I make use of them?

Those are [EAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969(v=vs.110).aspx) members. You need to [write TAP wrappers for those EAP members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178(v=vs.110).aspx#EAP); then you can use `async`/`await` like normal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use async/await, the correct approach is as you suggested: change the validateLogin to `public static async Task validateLoginAsync(...)`  The method that calls validateLogin needs to be changed, and the one calling it, etc.

It may be possible for you to use `AsyncContext` or `NotifyTaskCompletion` as a crutch (from https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext) but you still may need to use a BackgroundWorker or similar construct as well.